# Some confusion about usage of the termdebug( a pulugin within vim) in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Recently I have been using vim termdebug to debug my code.

I found one of the feature which is really helpful is that: if I put my cursor on the letter or sytax I will get the value of it.

When the feature works:

[image: When the feature works]

However,sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

,and I am a bit confused why this happended?

here is my vimrc about this pulugin

```
packadd termdebug
let g:termdebug_wide=1
```

The plugin didn't report any error message when I used it.

What can I do to make sure I have this feature every time I use it?

I would appreciate it if you give me some suggestions.

When the feature didn't work:

[image: When the feature didn't work]

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help people find a solution to your problem, I think you will need to give more information - Did you change anything that may have caused the error? Was there some kind of error message? Also, please favour putting the text directly in the Q instead of an image. You can highlight the text and use `ctrl` + `k` to indent it and make it appear as a formatted code block (or surround with ``` - see syntax highlighting for code in https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also this Q might get a better response at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look at the vi.stackexchange.com